# any difference on phrases: "old foggy London" and "foggy old London"?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

Can these phrases be interpreted differently:

1 - old foggy London

2 - foggy old London

I tend to think the first imply London has always been foggy and the second that Lodon became foggy at one point of its existence. Make any sense?

Comment: Research order of adjectives.

Comment: I don't think there is any difference in meaning. "[Adjective] old [noun]" is a common combination which can be either affectionate or contemptuous - "Good old Jim" - "nasty old thing".

Comment: Off-topic I guess, but it annoys Brits when they hear from foreigners that London is 'foggy'. It hasn't been seriously foggy for 60 years or more.

Comment: @KateBunting - yes, you could say 'good old Jim' even if Jim is aged 20.

Answer (score -1):

There are three uses of the word "old" that could be intended in these sentences:

1. Constructed a long time ago. The typical meaning of "old".
2. Former; original. Used of cities to denote some area that comes from an old*er* period than the rest.
3. An intensifier or familiarizer or even meaningless particle, as in "good old Dan" (Dan is not actually old).

"Old, foggy London" has the first meaning. London is old and foggy.

"Foggy Old London" (note capitalization) has the second meaning. Old London (a part of the city) is foggy.

"Foggy old London" has the third meaning. London, that jolly old city of ours, is foggy.

*Maybe* you could argue that "foggy old London" could have the first meaning as well, but it sounds like the wrong order of adjectives to me.

Comment: do you think the phases: "English native speaker"  and "native English speaker" could be understood to mean the same thing of course with the listener realizing the speaker is not a native speaker of English or do you think thse phrases could differ in meaning? I ask you that because the phrase: "native English speaker" made think of "old foggy..." and "foggy old..." example

Comment: @fabianoluna No, "English native speaker" sounds plain wrong. I think it's only because of the flexibility of "old" that there are multiple possibilities for the London example.

Comment: _Native_ qualifies the phrase _English speaker_, not just _speaker_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, could "English" qualify: "native speaker" so that would be a native speaker of English?

Comment: @Kate Bunting, I mean why "technically" English can't qualify "native speaker"?

Comment: To me, _English native speaker_ would mean 'a native speaker from England', and _native speaker_ means nothing without a language.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, yes a native speaker of English. That is what I mean. so you're saying: "English native speaker" and "native English speaker" means the same thing?

Comment: **No.** I'm agreeing with Luke that _English native speaker_ sounds wrong. I'm a native [English speaker], not an English [native speaker] (of what? If my parents had come to England from overseas I might have learned another language from birth.)

Comment: @Kate Bunting, I get your point. It is a little confusing because I think the answer I'm looking for would be just WHY can't English qualify "native speaker" as though english was an adjective modifying native speaker. get it? I thought [native speaker] could be a compund noun and English an adjective.

Comment: @fabianoluna They *are* a compound noun and adjective respectively. But the result is that "English" can't, so to speak, get into the compound and modify the language. "Native speaker" is a unit, with an implied language (presumably not English because of the order). That leaves "English" to modify the nationality of the unit. Here's an example: I'm in Nigeria among people who speak Yoruba. I have a native speaker of Yoruba with me, and he's English in nationality. I might call him an "English native speaker". Like Kate, that's the only interpretation I can meaningfully apply.